# Should 'TV' in 'Q&A for movie and tv enthusiasts' be capitalized?

Tags: discussion

The [list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) describes this site as

> Q&A for movie and tv enthusiasts

This description is also visible on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts).

It's about the only place where 'tv' is spelled lowercase; would it make sense to change it to 'TV'? (If so, the ♦ moderators can forward this request to Stack Exchange staff.)